# Replace "." by "," in float column and BigDecimal column

Tags: java

I want to replace "." by ","  in a Float Column .

Here is my code .

I'm i missing something in the conversion Part ?

```
public static Float    replace_float(Float  x) {

    if ( x!=null && !"".trim().equals(x) ) {
        
        return   Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(x).replace(".", ","))  ; 
    }
   
    return   Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(x).replace(".", ","))  ; 
}
```

Comment: you might want to take a look at NumberFormat class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about the output format of a `float`. Because only when your `float` is to be displayed is it converted into a string and, depending on the language settings on the computer, it is output with a point or a comma. If you want to change that, you do not have to change anything on the `Float`, you only have to format it accordingly during the output.

For example, you could use the German number format to display your `Float` with a comma.

```
public String commaFloat(Float yourValue){
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    nf.setGroupingUsed(false);
    return nf.format(yourValue);
}
```

I hope you find the answer helpful.

Comment: Thanks , tested it and response was very clear and helpful

Answer (score 2):

A `Float` does not contain **either** a `.` **nor** a `,`. It holds purely the numeric value that it represents.

The choice of formatting it with a `.` or a `,` is made at the point where you transform it into a `String`.

In other words: if you want to distinguish the **presentation** of a given numeric value, you must use a data type such as `String`.

And use something like `DecimalFormat` to produce that `String`.

Comment: Could you give me an example ? However i want to return a Float not a String  .

Comment: You can not return "a `Float` with a specific decimal separator", that concept simply doesn't work. If I give you 1 dollar and 50 cents you can't go "But I'd like $1,50 and not $1.50", that's simply a nonsensical request.